# Permisos httpd en centos

Tags: linux, web, apache2

Tengo un servicio httpd corriendo, en el documentroot tengo un proyecto web que esta funcionando con permisos y grupo apache.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El lio es, que quiero configurar un usuario ftp para que pueda acceder a editar archivos solo a esta carpeta, por lo tanto, tendria que cambiar el propietario apache, por ejemplo por el usuario votacion, el cual al acceder por ftp funciona, pero entonces cuando abra la pagina por el navegador, obtengo un error de permisos, asi que tengo que dejar todos los archivos con propietario apache, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que apache me valide un usuario o propietario diferente a apache?

Comment: Añade el usuario ftp al grupo *apache* y otorga permiso de escritura al grupo.

Comment: Gracias Sal, efectivamente, hice lo que me dijo y puedo ingresar por ftp, pero ahora no puedo crear ni editar archivos

Comment: Ya lo arregle, tuve que dar permisos de escritura al grupo, ahora, como puedo hacer para decirle a apache, que un usuario tambien tiene derecho a leer y escribir, pero cuando se abra el navegador, tambien le de ese permiso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para evitar el problema de permisos lo mejor que puedes hacer es ponerte PHP-FPM de manera que sea el mismo usuario que estés usando para "subir" y "ejecutar" PHP, así también evitas problemas con la caché.

Aquí tienes un manual sencillo de como instalar PHP-FPM en [Centos6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) y [Centos7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7), ya que no se cual de los dos estás usando.

Una vez tengas correctos los permisos, puedes usar el mismo usuario para realizar modificaciones sin problemas.

Aún así te recomiendo algún sistema de `deploy` automático que te ayudará muchísimo para evitar problemas.

Te puede valer cualquiera de estos dos:

- [Deployer](https://deployer.org/)
- [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/)